# numactl: this system does not support NUMA policy

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto, numa

When using numactl, I was seeing

```
numactl: this system does not support NUMA policy.
```

Is it because some kernel config is not enabled?

Confirmed BIOS enabled NUMA.

lscpu shows there are NUMA nodes.

Comment: Please provide the exact command you're running and the numactl version you are using if possible.

Comment: lscpu output as well (couldn't edit the above comment to add this request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

NUMA ACPI is probably disabled from (A) BIOS or (B) cmdline or (C) kernel config. See details below.

**More details**

Looking at the numactl source code (from [github](https://github.com/numactl/numactl)), I see that the error above is coming from the checknuma() function:

```
void checknuma(void)
{
    static int numa = -1;
    if (numa < 0) {
            if (numa_available() < 0)
                    complain("This system does not support NUMA policy");
    }
    numa = 0;
}
```

Which would fail when numa_available() return value is less than 0. This would only happen when get_mempolicy() syscall would fail with the error code ENOSYS:

```
int numa_available(void)
{
    if (get_mempolicy(NULL, NULL, 0, 0, 0) < 0 && errno == ENOSYS)
            return -1;
```

ENOSYS error correlates to 'Function not implemented', so it looks like NUMA isn't supported by your system. Since this support was added to the kernel long ago (kernel v2.6.7), than it is probably a configuration issue:

1. NUMA support is disabled in BIOS (you mention you verified this).
2. NUMA ACPI is disabled either from:

   1. cmdline - check for acpi=off in /prco/cmdline
   2. kernel config - check for CONFIG_X86_64_ACPI_NUMA=y and CONFIG_ACPI_NUMA=y.

Make sure CONFIG_NUMA=y is set as well.
See more details in [this article](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-how-to-find-if-numa-configuration-is-enabled-or-disabled/).

Hope this helps.

PS - you didn't mention which kernel are you running and if this is bare-metal or VM/docker. If the latter, the get_mempolicy() sysctl might be blocked. See more information [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-run-numactl-interleave-all-in-docker/40631).